# How to properly use jq in ansible shell tasks

Tags: shell, ansible, jq

I'm trying to use yq/jq in an ansible shell task.

My task has taken a few different forms, but none of them have worked so far. I've tried multiline and on one line.

Here's the task I'd like to run.  I'm getting the quotes wrong somehow and haven't been able to figure it out.

Here some simple yaml - simple-service-test.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        -
          args:
            - proxy
            - "--statusPort"
            - "15020"
            - "--applicationPorts"
            - "2525"
```

Content of myjq.txt

```
.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args as $myarray | $myarray | length as $mylength | $myarray[($mylength - 1)] |= $portVal
```

My test ansible playbook

```
  ---
- name: Test yq shell
  hosts: localhost 

  tasks:
  - name: Run yq
    shell: yq --arg portVal "8443" -f {{ playbook_dir }}/myjq.txt simple-service-test.yaml > output.txt
```

Which can be run all files in the same folder, as `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`  When I run this using ansible 2.3 or 2.7 locally, it works and outputs the correct content. When I run the same thing in a build, ansible calls yq and i get `` jq: jv.c:199: jvp_array_write: Assertion `i >= 0' failed. ``

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Before this is answerable, we need to have enough information *to generate the same problem ourselves*. Right now this code won't run without other things in your playbook; can you generate a playbook that anyone can use? That way anyone here can test whether their proposed fix actually solves your problem.

Comment: I've added a playbook and changed the command I'm running yq with, as shown above.  There's also a file called myjq.txt which contains the filter I'd like to apply, as well as a simple test yaml.  Basically, I just want to change the value right after "applicationPorts"

Answer (score 1):

"`.Values`" is not a valid Ansible variable name. Quoting from [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. Variables should always start with a letter.

Expansion of the dictionary below

```
"{{ .Values.global.aService.inner_port }}"
```

must fail

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: {{ .Values.global.aService.inner_port }}"}
```

(There might be other problems in the run-string)

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I fixed the variable reference and edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The segment

```
--arg portVal "{{ .Values.global.aService.inner_port }}"
```

looks wrong in several ways.

First, one cannot simply pass in a jq program fragment
such as `.Values.global_service.inner.port` via the command line. If you want a dynamic lookup, you could use the array representation of a path, e.g. `["Values","global_service","inner","port"]`. Or you could programmatically convert the string representation of the path into the array representation.

Second, if you do want to pass in a JSON value other than a string, it would be better to use `--argjson` than `--arg`.

Finally, the duplication of the braces (`{{...}}`) looks as though you're mixing ansible magic with yq/jq syntax in an unhappy way.

It would probably be helpful if you could post the input that yq sees, or at least a relevant YAML or JSON fragment.

Comment: I was trying to use an ansible variable, but incorrectly.  I fixed my issue that Vlad pointed out and am now getting the right port value passed in at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked it down. The output from kube-inject was putting "---" at the end of the output. When I remove that, the assertion error above goes away. So I guess I'll need to run `sed -i '$ d' simple-service-test.yaml` before running yq against this content.